# Script to extract search query or a term after a specific string

Tags: ruby, regex, linux

I'm trying to extract a search term that I logged in a log file.

I'm logging every search term in a log file like

```
The search request for 'John' identified as ...
```

I'd like to extract word 'John' from this log file and put it into another text file.

For Example `search_log.txt` file has following lines:

```
The search request for 'John' identified as ...
The search request for 'Peter Parker' identified as ...
The search request for 'Iron man' identified as ...
The search request for 'Naruto Uzumaki' identified as ...
The search request for 'Chuck Norris' identified as ...
```

The script should extract words John, Peter Parker, Iron man, Naruto Uzumaki, Chuck Norris and put them into a `output.txt`, one line for each term.

Or a ruby function that extracts these words and save them into an array.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep -o "search request for '[^']*'" input.txt | awk -F\' '{print $2}' > output.txt
$ cat output.txt
John
Peter Parker
Iron man
Naruto Uzumaki
Chuck Norris
```

First **grep** looks for all occurrences of the string "search request for" followed by the name of the guy in single quotes, and then we use **awk** to clean the string so that we retain only the name of the people, one per line.

This solution with `grep -o` works irrespective of whether the input is all on one line or on several. If the input is guaranteed to be as simple as the OP's example, then we could go for simpler one-step solutions, for instance with **awk** only:

```
$ awk -F\' '{print $2}' input.txt
```

But the above works only if the input displays one instance on each line, and not if there are escaped single quotes in the names. Accepting several "search request for" per line, there is also:

```
$ awk -F\' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i}' input.txt
```

And finally, if the input is really, really so simple, with exactly one instance per line, we can go with **cut**:

```
$ cut -d\' -f2 input2.txt
```

All these answers are really easy to find out by just reading a manpage or looking at other similar questions asked on SO... :(

Comment: +1 for squeezing your answer through the linux crack

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a ruby solution, this would print each name in search_log.txt to command line:

```
File.open("search_log.txt", "r") do |f|
  puts f.read.scan(/'(.*)'/)
end
```

It's opening and reading the [file](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html), [scanning](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-scan) for strings enclosed in single quotes, and [printing](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) those strings to console.

And this approach returns an array with the extracted strings:

```
def get_names(file)
  file.read.scan(/'(.*)'/).flatten!
end

names = File.open("search_log.txt", "r") do |f|
  get_names(f)
end

puts names.class
#=> Array

puts names
#=> John
#=> Peter Parker
#=> Iron man
#=> Naruto Uzumaki
#=> Chuck Norris
```

Then you can generate an output.txt file based on the array that's returned:

```
File.open("blah.txt", "w+") do |f|
  names.each { |name| f.write "#{name}\n" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

logfile.log:

```
The search request for 'John' identified as ... 
Error: server crashed
The search request for 'Peter Parker' identified as ... 
The search request for 'Iron man' identified as ... 
The search request for 'Naruto Uzumaki' identified as ...
Error: 'DivisionByZeroError'
The search request for 'Chuck Norris' identified as ...
The search request for '' identified as ... will not be recorded
And if the search request for 'Abbey' is here, do not record name...
```

prog.rb:

```
infile = 'logfile.log'
outfile = 'logged_names.txt'

File.open(outfile, 'w') do |f|  #Open outfile for writing
  IO.foreach(infile) do |line|  #Open infile for reading and step through each line 
    md = line.match(/\AThe search request for '(.+?)'/)  #md => MatchData object or nil
    f.puts md[1] if md    #match() returns nil if there is no match; if there is a match, md[0] is whole match, md[1] is what matched the first parenthesized group in regex
  end   #infile automatically closed here
end   #outfile automatically closed here
```

...

```
~/ruby_programs$ ruby prog.rb 
~/ruby_programs$ cat logged_names.txt 
John
Peter Parker
Iron man
Naruto Uzumaki
Chuck Norris
```